# Rails find all products which belong to a collection of categories

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, one-to-many

So lets say that I have a Product and Category model. There is a one to many relationship between them ( category has many products, product belongs to category ). 
I create a collection of categories based on certain criterias using a named scope. Lets call this collection A.
Then I would like to create a collection of products which belongs to either category in collection A.

How can I do this?

My guess would be to use the ids of collection A ( A.ids ) and use map or lambda to check if the category_id of a product is included in the array of ids I built from collection A. I am not sure how to do this exactly, and if is the most efficient way to achieve the end result.

Comment: Please provide your model details and relationship?? collection is what seperate model or not??

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to arrange your models like this:

```
class Category
  has_many :products
  has_many :category_collections
end

class CategotyCollection
  belongs_to :category
  belongs_to :collection
end

class Collection
  has_many :category_collections
  has_many :categories, through: :category_collections
  has_many :products, through: :categories
```

end

In the end of the day, you can select products in given collection as simple:

```
collection = CategoryCollection.first
collection.categories # => all categories in this collection
collection.products # => all products in this collection
```

Comment: Hi Dimakura! Thanks for the answer. "has_many :categories" - It seems if I set it up this way then a category can belong to 1 collection only, but what if I would like to create more collections, and a certain category can belong to more than one of them? If I set up a many to many relationship between CategoryCollection and Category would it still be the solution You suggest?

Comment: Do you mean `has_and_belongs_to_many :categories`? It should still be workable.

Comment: I mean creating another join table. Lets say CategoryConnection ( category_collection_id, category_id ). Then in CategoryCollection I would define the relationship this way: has_many :categories, through: :category_connections . This way 1 category can belong to more than one CategoryCollection.

Comment: @MateKaszas I've updated my answer. I renamed `CategoryCollection` to `Collection`. It should work in this way.

Answer (score 1):

I'd be tempted to employ a [`has_many :through`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association) relationship, although it's really just a "join" model that's required:

[image]

I originally thought of a `has_and_belongs_to_many` relationship, but that wouldn't be able to discern the different categories.

--

```
#app/models/collection.rb
class Collection < ActiveRecord::Base
   #columns id | name | category_id | product_id
   belongs_to :category
   belongs_to :product
end
```

Having a `Collection` model like this will give you the ability to call the following:

```
@collection = Collection.find_by name: "New products"
@collection.categories #-> all categories
@collection.products #-> all products
```

This will give you the ability to relate the `products` and `categories` as follows:

```
#app/models/product.rb
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :categories
   has_many :collections
   has_many :collection_categories, through: :collections
end

#app/models/category.rb
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :products
   has_many :collections
   has_many :collection_products, through: :collections
end
```

Changing your `Product` and `Category` models is optional. It would be for if you wanted the following:

```
@category = Category.find "1"
@category.collection_products # -> pulled from collections (IE not the `has_many/belongs_to` relationship you have now.


@product = Product.find "2"
@product.collection_categories # -> all categories through the collections table
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Join on association, filter by accociated objects (`joins`/`merge` combo)

   ```
   Product.joins(:category).merge(Category.whatever_scope(you, have))
   ```
2. Subquery on association

   ```
   Product.where(category: Category.whatever_scope(you, have))
   ```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is actually to take ids and use them to select products.

```
category_ids = Category.some_scope.pluck(:id)
products_collection = Product.where(category_id: category_ids)
```

Unless it is not always - that you need to select products from many categories - then maybe you should do that way with collection model, that suggested @dimakura

Answer (score 0):

When you say that you "would like to create a collection of products which belongs to ***either*** category in collection A" that automatically makes it a **many to many** relationship. In reality one product can belong to many categories, and a category can have many products. Therefore, I would create a join table to solve your issue.

Comment: Hi David! I agree that in a real world app, a product should be able to belong to more than one category. I only used these 2 model names to outline a certain problem I would like to solve here though. So in this case a product has a category_id field which contains the id of the category this product belongs to. On the other end I have a collection of categories. Lets say X(id = 34),Y(id=35),Z(id=36). So I would like to select all products that have either 34,35 or 36 in their category_id field.